# Making query return rows that meet the criteria of a drop down in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, dropdown, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I am trying to have query search through named range SubListTable ('Sub List'!A1:I188) on a column of that table named Instrument ('Sub List'!D:D) and return only rows that have an instrument from a drop down SubByInstrument!A2

The SubByInstrument sheet is on the same page as the query.

Currently my query which will only return an error is as follows:

```
=QUERY(SubListTable,"SELECT * Where "Instrument""=""A2""",-1)")
```

I know that Instrument and A2 are correctly referencing what I want, where A2 is a a drop-down that will allow us to look at people who specialize in that instrument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if A2 is text string try:

```
=QUERY({SubListTable}, "where Col4 = '"&A2&"'", -1)
```

if A2 is number use:

```
=QUERY({SubListTable}, "where Col4 = "&A2, -1)
```

Comment: The text string suggestion works like a charm.  I want to learn about why col4 works and also why the curly brackets work and even the rules behind the amerpsand and quotations.  Unless you feel inclined to give a mini lesson, do you have any resources you would recommend where I could feel competent explaining how this all works?

Comment: you mean step further like: `=QUERY({SubListTable}, "where Col4 = '"&A2&"' and Col5 = 'some text'", -1)` ?

Comment: sure, I can explain... query works in two modes if range is `A:B` query syntax shall be `"select A,B"` if you wrap range in `{}` like `{A:B}` syntax needs to be: `"select Col1,Col2"`. having named range instead of regular range is same. then in query syntax all text strings needst to be wrapped into single quotes ' ' example: `"where A = 'text'"` but for numbers applies that numbers should be standalone so: `"where A=8"`

Comment: Can I ask you how to take this one step further, if I want to check if other columns meet the same criteria?  Like why does the following not work

=QUERY({'Sub List'!A1:G188}, "where Col4 = '"&A1&"'OR where Col5 ='"&A1&"' OR where Col6 ='"&A1&"OR where Col7 ='"&A1&"'", 1)

Thank you for all your help!

Comment: you can have only 1 "where". try like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5XOe.png